# How is an object constructed if {} is used?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I have a class:

```
class Book
{
public:

    Book() { ID++; }

    int GetID() const { return ID; }

private:

    static int ID;
};

int Book::ID = 0;
```

Now I can create a book like this `Book* book{}` or like this `Book* book = new Book()`
I was assuming that in both versions the default constructor is being called.

Bit if I do this:

```
for (int i{} ; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        if (Book* book = new Book(); book->GetID() > 5)
        {
            cout << "ID > 5" <<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "ID < 5"<<endl;
        }
    }
```

then result is : 5 books with ID<5 and 5 with ID>5
if I do it this way:

```
 for (int i{} ; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        if (Book* book{}; book->GetID() > 5)
        {
            cout << "ID > 5" <<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "ID < 5"<<endl;
        }
    }
```

then result is: all books have ID<5

The fact that I can call `GetID()` means there is a non nullptr object I call this method from.
But there is also no other constructor than the default one.
So what is really happening when I create an object of a Book like this:
`Book* book{}`
?

Comment: `Book* book{}` is the default constructor for a *pointer*, which will set `book` to `nullptr`.  *The fact that I can call `GetID()` means there is a non nullptr object I call this method from.*  No, it does not mean that it is non-nullptr; it means that if it is nullptr then the behavior is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks! I was super sure it has to crash if its nullptr and just assumed if it does not crash than its a valid object.

Comment: Technically, a member function will be called with `this` being a null pointer. Unless you actually access `this`, no crash is expected (but it's still UB, of course). You don't need `this` to call a non-`virtual` member function and to access a `static` data member. Try to replace `static` data member with a non-static one and see what happens then.